# What does it mean to rewrite a polynomial in monomial form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

I'm told that P(x) can be rewritten in standard (polynomial) form if we rearrange it algebraically, so P(x) is definitely a polynomial. What does it mean to rewrite a polynomial in monomial form? Does that mean it should only have a single term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "as a sum of monomials", as opposed to right now, when it's a large fraction with $\frac1x$-like terms in the numerator and denominator. In essence, they're asking you to simplify away the large fraction, and make it *clearly visible* that this is indeed a polynomial. You're told that it can be done? They're asking you to actually do it.